# Tornado: HTML inside gettext function string

Tags: html, tornado, gettext

I am using gettext for internationalisation. I have HTML tags in one sentence, but after translation the HTML tags are shown as string.

```
msgid "<strong>Dokument(e)</strong> offline verfuegbar machen<br>"
msgstr "<strong> Dokument(e)</strong> offline verfügbar machen<br>"
```

Does someone has more experience with this?

I need this output: **Dokument(e)** offline verfügbar machen 
but the output is: `"<strong> Dokument(e)</strong> offline verfügbar machen<br>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings contain html, you must use a `raw` template expresssion. Use `{% raw _("my string") %}` instead of `{{ _("my string") }}`.